How can I plot polygon numbers from a shapefile in python?
I would like to plot each polygon's number within the polygon (not usually done). I am able to write the polygon names to a csv file with the following code;
import geopandas as gpd

gdf1 = gpd.read_file("path/to/shapefile")
gdf= = gpd.read_file("path/to/shapefile")

gdf = gdf['geometry'].representative_point()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5))
gdf1.plot(ax=ax,color='none', edgecolor='r', linewidths=1.8)
gdf.plot(ax=ax)

plt.show()

I have tried to get the index of each polygon and write these to csv with
gdf=shp['index']
gdf.to_csv("Shpindices.csv")

Once I get the indices, I can plot them with basemap.
Question is, is it possible to access the indices this way, or can one actually plot the indices in the shapefile. I cannot find anything, googling pandas tutorials.

You could find the mean x and mean y of the polygon, and then use plt.text or plt.annotate to position text at that location.

Thanks @MuhammedYunus, I will try that

In addition to @MuhammedYunusStopTheGenocide: Geopandas as a centroid function that can create centroids points. You can use these to generate the points where you want to annotate your polygon names.

In addition to @MuhammedYunusStopTheGenocide: Geopandas as a centroid function that can create centroids points. You can use these to generate the points where you want to annotate your polygon names
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
gdf = gpd.read_file("data.shp")

gdf["centroid"] = gdf.geometry.centroid

# Plot polygons
ax = gdf.plot()
for _, row in gdf.iterrows():
    x, y = row["centroid"].x, row["centroid"].y
    ax.text(x, y, row["naam"], fontsize=8)

plt.show()


Thaks @DanielL for effort and time. Command gdf["centroid"] = gdf.geometry.centroid gives the warning "UserWarning: Geometry is in a geographic CRS. Results from 'centroid' are likely incorrect. Use 'GeoSeries.to_crs()' to re-project geometries to a projected CRS before this operation."
What works is "gdf = gdf['geometry'].representative_point()". plt.show after thsi command plot the shapefile with a dot at the shapefile centroid,
For loop gives the error "AttributeError: 'GeoSeries' object has no attribute 'iterrows'. Did you mean: 'interiors'?"
However, this takes me close to what I want.

see edited code which gives some result.
